# Define custom _repr_html_ to suppress output from object in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Jupyter has a [flexible system](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html) for customizing rich representations of objects. For example, the REPL output for objects of this class will be colorful:

```py
class ColorfulText:
    def __init__(self, string, color):
        self.content = f"<p style='color: {color}'>{string}</p>"
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return self.content
```

Is it possible to use this system to **completely suppress** the REPL output for objects of a specific class? It is possible to get a *blank* output, e.g. with

```py
class Blank:
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return ""
```

but this maintains a cell output prompt and a blank line. I would instead like the object to be treated as equivalent to `None` (which has no REPL output) in the context of the notebook interface.

PS: if this is otherwise possible through alternate methods (like Jupyter's [display formatters](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.formatters.html), which seem slightly different, or even using built-in Python functionality), that's acceptable too. But ideally, output suppression would happen only in a notebook.

PPS: I know it is possible in user-space to suppress output, e.g. by catching the return value or puttin a semi-colon at the end of the line. But I am looking for a solution that does not require user intervention.